# R: dplyr::lag throws error when trying to lag characters in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, tibble

I'm getting the following error in R when I try to use the lag function (from the dplyr library) on a column of characters in a tibble:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Expecting a single string
>   value: [type=logical; extent=1].

This error does not occur for a column of characters in a data frame. I also don't get the error for a column of numbers in either a tibble or a data frame.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this discrepancy in the lag function for data frames versus tibbles? Thanks!

Here is some sample code that reproduces the error. I have examples of both when lag works and when it doesn't. I have tried updating the tidyverse and dplyr libraries on my machine but I'm still getting the same error.

```
tib = data_frame(x = c('a','b','c'), y = 1:3)

# lagging column of characters in tibble throws error
res = tib %>%
    mutate(lag_n = lag(x, n=1, default = NA))

# lagging column of numbers in tibble does NOT throw error
res = tib %>%
    mutate(lag_c = lag(y, n=1, default = NA))

df = data.frame(x = c('a','b','c'), y = 1:3)

# lagging column of characters in data frame does NOT throw error
res = df %>%
    mutate(lag_n = lag(x, n=1, default = NA))

# lagging column of numbers in data frame does NOT throw error
res = df %>%
    mutate(lag_c = lag(y, n=1, default = NA))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running into this error because `dplyr` and `tibble` are strict about the type of `NA` values that they allow you to use (or, more specifically, they are more strict about checking the type of the variable you create).  You needed `NA_character_`, like so:

```
res = tib %>%
    mutate(lag_n = lag(x, n=1, default = NA_character_))
```

Comment: I knew that this was something you needed to do, but do you happen to know why you don't have to specify `NA_integer_` or `NA_real_`? `NA` is logical by default, after all. Plus, the function works if you just leave out the `default` argument and let it default to `NA`, which you would think is the same thing.

Comment: @CalumYou Unfortunately, I have no idea.  I don't know the ins and outs of how `dplyr` treats `NA` values well enough.  I just recognized this as a similar error to the one you get when you use `dplyr::if_else` vs `base::ifelse`.

Comment: yeah, i just tried to understand the mutate source and failed once it got deep into rcpp :(.